# How to Change the Order of taxonomy in term store SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store

How do i rearrange taxonomy term store from the top to bottom ? I just did delete and add again, but its the same issue happened. Still at the top of the global nav under technical

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the TermStore is different on SP-Online vs On-Prem, but on the assumption they're functionally the same...

**Click on the Term Set** that you want (1). In the ribbon to the top of the term set interface, select **Custom Sort** (2). Then select **Use Custom Sort Order** (3). From there you can select the order you want the term sets in, rather than an alpha-numeric order.

Then click save, and refresh the page. The terms should be in your specified order.

[image]